# Real life usage of unbounded wilcard

Tags: java, wildcard, unbounded-wildcard

As far as I understand unbounded wildcard statement (`?`) could be used only at the method argument level and only for collections.

Could someone please give me an example from his or her real experience where this can be helpful? I mean an example of unbounded wildcard usage as a solution for some production-like assignment.

Thanks in advance!